# from javascript to jinja2

Tags: getjson, jinja2

Is it possible to access data obtained via .getJSON call in jquery as a jinja2 variable ?

```
 $.getJSON(
            $SCRIPT_ROOT +"/gitem/"+node.id,
            function(data){
                if (data.length > 0){

                    $.each(data, function(index,val_dict) {




                        var button_id = "button_"+String(index);
                        var popup_id = "element_to_pop_up_"+String(index);

                        var append_string = sprintf('<div class="icony"><img src="%s"  height="75" id="%s" >%s</div>',val_dict.img_url,button_id,val_dict.img_caption);
                        var bpopup_element = sprintf('<div id="%s"><a class="bClose"><img src="%s" width="500px">X<a/></div>',popup_id,val_dict.img_url)

                    $('.data_area').append(append_string+bpopup_element);

                        $('#'+popup_id).hide();

                        $('#'+button_id).bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#'+popup_id).bPopup();

                        });

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    var append_string = '<div class="icony">No Images to display for this category</div>';
                    $('.data_area').append(append_string);
                }

                $("#list_viewer").css("display", "block");
            });
```

For example in the above I am getting the data and then constructing the DOM within js. While what would be best would be to import data via .getJSON and then set the data as a jinja2 variable.

Later I can use that variable within jinja2 template ?

it that possible ?

---

or better still...

can a jinja macro be called from within the .getJSON function  ? that can also allow embedding of json data within jinja2....

thanks for any pointer...

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Jinja generally runs on the server, rendering your web site templates before sending them off to the client. The client (i.e. your web browser) will not have access to the templates.

If you'd like to use Jinja templates to render client-side JSON objects, you could take a look at [Jasinja](https://bitbucket.org/djc/jasinja), which is a tool to convert your Jinja templates to JavaScript, which you can then use in the browser. A number of similar tools exist.

Finally, another solution is to send your JSON data to the web server, render them to HTML via Jinja, then send back the resulting HTML in the XMLHttpRequest response. However, if you've obtained this JSON data from the same server you use to render templates, you might be better off just having HTML sent to the client directly and added to the DOM from there.